# Remove cut, copy,paste popup from iOS devices

Tags: html, css, cordova, ios11

I am working on an cordova application. In my application I have written some code to select all the text inside the input box on click event. This works totally fine as per the requirement and no problems whatsoever.The code to select all the text is as follows

```
function SelectText(sender)
{
    var input = document.activeElement;
    var value = input.value;
    var len = value.length;
    input.setSelectionRange(0,len);    
}
```

But as the text entire text inside an input textbox is selected a popup with Cut,Copy,Paste is shown to the user by iOS device. But I don't want user to see this popup. Is there any way we can remove the the popup or prevent the popup from appearing but keeping the text selected?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use Jquery?

Comment: Yes I can use jQuery.

Comment: Is this of any use of you? [Hide Ipad Cut Copy Paste menu](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/hide-ipad-cut-copy-paste-menu). I am not known with developing for IOS but I CAN google around :)

Comment: I have tried this code but not working in my case.

Comment: Not working as in errors or it just does not change anything?

Comment: The cut,copy,paste popup keep appearing. Does not change anything

Comment: Are you able to inspect it or something? If you can find out the id or class you may be able to use styling like `display:none;` to hide it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162989/discussion-between-nikhil-and-granny).